# Invalid Column name 'Price'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a SQL If-Else Statement in SQL Server but my query displayed a error which is Invalid Column Name 'Price' but I have that column on my table. Do I need to declare it in the If-Else Statement? Here is my query:

```sql
IF Price > 2000000
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Wow! The Sales amount which is 3,000,000 is much higher than the 2,000,000 amount of Year 2018';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'The Sales amount did not surpass the 2,000,000 of 2018';
END
```

I have two columns. The column names are Year and Price. I have 2018 and 2019 for my Year column. I have 2,000,000 and 3,000,000 for my Price Column.

Comment: `IF Price > 2000000` doesn't make any sense, `Price` has no context. Perhaps you mean a variable `@Price`? This, however, feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). `PRINT` isn't intended to give the application user information; it's for the output window so better suited for debug messages and stuff. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I already tried it earlier which is 
IF @Price > 2000000 but the error message is Must declare the scalar variable "@Price". I am trying to achieve is the statement block of true to be printed because the value that which is greater than 2,000,000 is 3,000,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Price` is a column in your table, you need to reference that table in some way.  I'm not sure how you're looking to use `Price` specifically but here are a couple of possibilities.

If you're just looking for at least one record in that table where `Price>2000000` then you could do something like this.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from tbl WHERE Price>2000000)
BEGIN
...
```

Or if you want to sum that column, you could add the sum to a variable and then check the variable.

```
declare @price INT
select @price=sum(Price) from tbl
IF @price>2000000
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! I didn't know that there was a EXISTS Operator. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't necessarily a great solution depending on what you intend.  This will return positive if there are ANY rows in the table where Price>2000000.  It isn't looking at specific rows or conditions unless you update the query.

Comment: Noted. I understand your point.